# SQLite Database in external sdcar

Tags: android

i am newbie to android .
.
I have problem that how to get external storage directory.In my device it is storage/sdcard1 path.

but it is also not working.

How can I set external storage directory path to db ?
PLease help.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to give more info. Show us the code you are using. Tell us what happens when it doesn't work. Any Logcat errors?

Comment: String mdb_name = "/sales.db";
final File ctronDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard1/");
co.mcurd_data_path_ = ctronDirectory.getPath() + mdb_name;

Answer (score 1):

Before answering this question I want you know something about the android framework..
Android contains default sqlite handling options which saves database file in internal storage directory
It is good practice to use it..
But still if you want to save in custom directory follow these instructions
By default android partitions the internal storage into a partition called SD card
which can be accessed by calling frameworks Function

```
File Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

But on some devices there is an option have external memory card
If that is your case you can do that by calling java function like this

```
new File("/mnt/sdcard1/");
```